# Subtract a variable from vector<int>, using for_each and lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

I would like to subtract a number from each element of a vector, if written in traditional C++, it should be like this:

```
vector<int> A; // a vector of size N
int value; // a value to subtracted
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    A[i] -= value;
```

However now, I would like to use `for_each` to make the code cleaner. For example, the code should be something like this (the following is incorrect):

```
for_each(A.begin(), A.end(), [](int& x, int v) { x -= v; });
```

But the lambda function cannot use variable `value`.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vector<int> A { 10, 20, 30 }; // a vector of size N
int value = 10; // a value to subtracted
```

Two choices:

```
for_each(A.begin(), A.end(), [value](auto& x) { x -= value; });
```

Or

```
for (auto& x : A)
    x -= value;
```

Comment: The vector isn't being used in the anonymous lambda function. There's no reason why a copy should be made.

Comment: what if I want to use multiple variables, saying x = x + value1 - value2, [value1, value2](auto &x) { x = x + value1 - value2; } is it correct?

Comment: By using only auto without &, we would actually make a copy of the value in the vector every iteration, so the substract operation would not affect the original vector, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

put value in the capture list and it compiles just fine:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [value](int &x) { x -= value; });
```